# What's the difference between AWS SSO and AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, amazon-cognito, cloudfoundry-uaa

Let's say I have a few clients: corporation x, y, z. each of those corporation has their employees and their SSO (mostly SAML but can be also OpenId or anything else).

I want to be able to integrate with their SSO so they can log in to my application without giving me their credentials. Something like cloudfoundry UAA. Which one should i use: AWS SSO or AWS Cognito? What's the difference?

Answer (score 48):

I am on the Amazon Cognito team.

**Amazon Cognito** is our identity management solution for developers building B2C or B2B apps for their customers, which makes it a **customer-targeted IAM and user directory solution**.

**AWS SSO** is focused on SSO for **employees accessing AWS and business apps**, initially with Microsoft AD as the underlying employee directory.

We plan to integrate Cognito User Pools and AWS SSO as part of our roadmap.

Comment: Is there any word on progress of integration between Cognito User Pools and AWS SSO yet please? Use case is to allow ALB authentication using Cognito backed by SSO as the user pool, meaning apps fronted by ALB could be seen as business apps by SSO. See https://serverfault.com/q/977052/406287.

Comment: You may not need cognito at all since ALB directly supports oidc integration with azure.

Comment: Can we have something like auth0? Cognito with SSO feature, as my case, im using id pool to connect my openid provider, let say i have 2 domains, i want them sso together with Cognito, is it possible currently?

Comment: user192344 :- I  am facing the same problem exactly as yours have you find any solution please help me

Comment: what is the difference under the hood?